# why is my text not wrapping around my image?

Tags: css

[image]This is my code ... I want the image to float to the left and the text to wrap. 
Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


            <img src="~/Images/COWH/Case Study Images/Broward County FL - Tree Planting at LLMS - 4-29-17 - Patrick Fitzgerald.jpg" class="pull-left img-responsive" />


            <h4>Broward County, FL</h4>

            <p>
                Broward County, the nation's eighteenth largest county, with a population of 1.7 million people, is located in Southeast Florida and is bordered by the
                Everglades and the Atlantic Ocean with endless opportunities for viewing and interacting with wildlife. While 2/3 of the county is located in the
                Everglades, the remaining urban area is a diverse, vibrant, urban community with parks, beaches, and green space
            </p>

            <p>
                Gardening for wildlife, protecting natural areas, and improving flyways for migratory wildlife are a priority for the County Commission, which formed the
                NatureScape Broward program in 2003 to encourage residents and businesses to create wildlife habitats. Broward County was certified as a Community Wildlife
                Habitat in 2005, and encourages its 31 municipalities to do the same. Successes include the re-establishment of the endangered Atala butterfly population,
                increased sea turtle nesting, and the first school district in the nation to be certified as a Schoolyard Habitat.  Perhaps the best example of achievement
                is the continued interest of residents to add native plants, protect water quality, and preserve their unique ecosystems for future generations.
            </p>

            <p>Diana, Broward County NatureScape Leader and Community Wildlife Habitat Team Leader</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

also here is what the result is:

Comment: Can you show the CSS?

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap grid is working the css is bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just specify a particular width and height of your image so that, your content can get some space.

```
img{
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much!! I am on a deadline.